# Assigning a role to a user in extended Asp.Net Identity 2 error Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, user-roles

I have extended AspNetUserRoles for my application where I have added a new FK column `ApplicationId` in `AspNetUserRoles` table. The idea behind this is to allow same user to be in different applications with same or different roles.
Everything seems Ok till I tried to add the same role to the same user but for a different application where I have started getting the error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUserRoles'.

Could please anyone help me to come out of this problem.

my IdenitityModels is as follow

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual AspNetApplications AspNetApplication { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUserRoles AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<AspNetApplications> AspNetApplications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

My AspNetApplications and AspNetUserRoles models are as follow

```
public class AspNetApplications
{
    [Key]
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}

public class AspNetUserRoles : IdentityUserRole
{
    [Key]
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
    public AspNetApplications AspNetApplications { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the code where I am adding a new entity of type AspNetUserRoles and it throws the error at `dbContext.SaveChanges()`

```
            var aspNetUserRole = new AspNetUserRoles
            {
                UserId = userId,
                RoleId = roleId,
                ApplicationId = applicationId,
            };

            dbContext.AspNetUserRoles.Add(aspNetUserRole);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdentityUserRole` implements a composite foreign key consistent of `UserId` and `RoleId`. Your subclass only has a key set for `ApplicationId`, so one of two things is happening:

1. The key is `ApplicationId`, in which case only one user role could ever be added for any given application.
2. The key is `UserId` and `RoleId`, and since it's the same user and same role, you're violating the constraint.

Essentially, you need to ensure that the composite key consists of `UserId`, `RoleId`, *and* `ApplicationId`. Since you can't control the base implementation of `IdentityUserRole`, the best way to ensure that would be to use fluent config. Add the following to your context class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>().HasKey(m => new { m.ApplicationId, m.UserId, m.RoleId });
}
```

Also, FWIW, you don't need to name your classes `AspNet*`. If you want the same table names, just decorate the class with `[Table("AspNetUserRoles")]`.

Comment: You are right Chris. I am intend to add ApplicationId as a composite key and I have tried your approach where I can see the ApplicationId as the composite key in that migration but it still throwing the same error. up script is as follow 
 DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "ApplicationId", "dbo.AspNetApplications");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "ApplicationId", "dbo.AspNetApplications", "ApplicationId");

Comment: You may need to blow out your database and recreate it. It doesn't seem like the migration is picking up the change from `OnModelCreating`. You did add that method to your `DbContext` subclass, correct?

Comment: I have got it working Thanks Chris. Foreign key data annotation was the problem. After removing the ForeignKey attribute and renaming my extended model class from AspNetUserRoles to ApplicationUserRoles it is working fine. Here I have another question. Migration has created a new table 'ApplicationUserRoles' with UserId,RoleId and ApplicationId as composite primary key. Can you please tell me how I can utilize this new table for role authentication rather the AspNetUserRoles table? My user claim identity still refering to AspNetUserRoles. Many Thanks